# Creating variables from list and accessing globally

Tags: python, variables, keyerror

I’m writing a program that pulls a list of departments from a database. I want to avoid hardcoding this since the list may change.

I want to create a variable for each department to populate questions into a GUI. The problem I have is that I can create variables from the database list using the vars() function. I’m then storing the list of variable names so I can reference them elsewhere in my program. As long as I do everything in the same def, there is no problem. But I don’t know how to reference the dynamically created variables in a separate function.

Since I won’t know the variable names ahead of time, I don’t know how to make them available in other functions.

```
deptList = ['deptartment 1', 'deptartment 2', 'deptartment 3', 'deptartment 4', 'deptartment4']

varList=[]

def createVariables():
    global varList    
    for i in range(len(deptList)):

        templst=deptList[i].replace(' ', '')
        varList.append(templst+'Questions')
        globals()['{}'.format(varList[i])] = []


def addInfo():
    global varList

    print('varlist',vars()[varList[1]]) #Keyerror



createVariables()
print(varList)
vars()[varList[1]].append('This is the new question')
print('varlist',vars()[varList[1]]) #Prints successfully

addInfo()
```

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous. Can you make it more clear what's certain and what's uncertain?

Comment: `globals()` just returns a dictionary. Can you not just create a custom dictionary for this? Why do you need global variables generated dynamically? And why does `vars()` return variables from the database? There must be a separate way you get the variable names and values from the database.

Comment: a dictionary might be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Using dynamically created global variables here seems inadvisable. Just use a `dict` object. There is no need for a `varsList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** use dynamic variables here. It makes no sense, just use one of Python's built-in containers, like a `dict`.

But, the reason your code isn't working is because `vars()` returns `locals()` when called with no argument. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> **vars**([object]) Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class,
>   instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.
>
> ...
>
> Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`. Note, the locals
>   dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals
>   dictionary are ignored.

So really, you just want to use the `dict` object returned by `globals()`. But this should make you wonder, why not just leave the global name-space out of it, and rather, just use your own custom `dict` object? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) related question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. I was able to write the code I needed with a dictionary. Being new to python, it took a little trial and error, but the solution was better than what I was originally trying to do.

Thanks for your help!